# If "git rm" doesn't work, what will?

Tags: git

I have tried to remove the "index.html" file for as I created it in the projects file by mistake.
I tried the git rm  command but get no success.
Also tried "git reset", "git reset --hard" but nothing will do.

```
User Documents $ cd projects
User (master) projects $ ls
BeachParadise   DasmotoProject  HelloWorld  RestaurantMenu  index.html
Broadway    HelloHtml   Paris   excursion
User (master) projects $ git rm index.html
fatal: pathspec 'index.html' did not match any files
User (master) projects $
```

Any thoughts on what I am missing here?
Thanks in advance

Comment: why not remove it from local and push another commit

Comment: You have not added index.html yet, so git does not know anything about it. Just remove it normally with `rm`.

Comment: Well... It looks likje index.html is not indexed in git. So you probably did not add it using `git add`. You can check that using `git status`. It should be on list of untracked files (marked in red). If so you can simply remove it from filesystem `rm index.html`

Comment: try "rm index.html"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is explained in the first paragraph of the documentation of [`git rm`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm):

> Remove files from the index, or from the working tree and the index. `git rm` will not remove a file from just your working directory. (There is no option to remove a file only from the working tree and yet keep it in the index; use `/bin/rm` if you want to do that.

Back to your case:

```
User (master) projects $ git rm index.html
fatal: pathspec 'index.html' did not match any files
```

`git rm index` clearly says it doesn't know anything about the file `index.html`. This means the file was never added to the repository or to the index (and it probably exists only in the working tree).

To remove the file from the directory simply run:

```
$ rm index.html
```

*Make sure you don't need the file any more as there is no way to recover it after you ran the command above.*